# Abp Dapper parsing ExtraProperties

Tags: abp

I received this error when using Dapper. My code: "(dbConnection.QueryAsync("select * from AbpUsers", transaction: await GetDbTransactionAsync())).ToList()"
=> Error:

- System.Data.DataException: 'Error parsing column 2 (ExtraProperties={} - String)'
- InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Volo.Abp.Data.ExtraPropertyDictionary'.

When I select only column "ExtraProperties" from table "IdentityUser" is work fine. My code: "(dbConnection.QueryAsync("select ExtraProperties from AbpUsers", transaction: await GetDbTransactionAsync())).ToList()"

Comment: If you want to map your extra properties, you can get a specific record or you can get it like a string and you can get a memory card.

Comment: Hi, You can not map your data to the model because of ExtraPropery. Could you have a look at this doc, please? https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Object-Extensions

Comment: I use a custom ITypeHandler to map ExtraPropertyDictionary.